# Protect against BigQuery spam

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, amazon-kinesis

I have the following software components:

- Amazon Kinesis event stream

  - Example event table: `product-purchase-events`
- BigQuery db receiving+storing events

  - Example query: `SELECT count(*) as count, DATE(timestamp) as day FROM product-purchase-events GROUP BY day`
- Microservice exposing an API do run a set of pre-defined BigQuery queries

  - Example endpoint: `GET /product-purchase-event/?step=DAY`
- Public web app consuming the query API to expose nice graphs

**Fact:** BigQuery bills per query and flatrate is very expensive.

**Problem:** if someone spams the `GET /product-purchase-event` endpoint, every call will execute a new query meaning after 1 million spam queries I will get a very nice bill.

**My question:** Can you spam protect BigQuery? I know there's a 24h cache, but I want data to be as real-time as possible.

I also know there are other solutions such as Amazon Redshift which bills per hour and not per query, but I wanted to know if I could solve this spam issue with BigQuery. It seems like most people use it for in-house only, meaning no external person can execute queries, so then spam isn't an issue.

Comment: Upvoted @shollyman 's answer. If latency is not a concern, periodically aggregating data into a much smaller table and hook up web front to the summary table could be an option. BigQuery cache works in this case. But if you really receives 1 million spam requests, I believe you will still be out of BigQuery query quota. shollyman suggested some way to cache results, which you should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've correctly surmised, its a Bad Idea(tm) to wire interactive public web endpoints to a handler that runs a BigQuery query directly.  There are multiple factors here including cost and latency.  Additionally, querying a table that's receiving streaming inserts means that you won't be able to leverage the basic BigQuery [caching mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#cache-exceptions) and will quickly reach concurrency limits once your public handler starts to get a reasonable amount of load.

A more typical pattern here is to compute your aggregates periodically via a BigQuery query, and then read and propagate those query results into a storage layer/system that's more appropriate for serving results in a point lookup fashion.  For example, something like datastore, or an in-memory keyvalue store, or even something like cloud SQL.

This decouples your serving architecture from the data processing, and the public handler is greatly simplified: it simply fetches the aggregate from the storage layer.

You can also deal with the "when do we recompute" with far more nuance.  You can define your processing to simply re-run on a fixed interval, leverage awareness of data staleness, or build some custom caching semantics based on other signals in your environment.